# osFormatType Endurance Block Storage ordering Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've done some searching online and can't seem to figure out why the OS format type is wrong. I Have done a query and the id and keyname is correct.

```
enduranceOrder = {
    "location": 1441195,
    "packageId": 240,
    "quantity": 48,
    "prices": [
        {
            "id": 45064 # endurance
        },
        {
            "id": 45104 # block storage
        },
        {
            "id": 178501 # 10 IOPS
        },
        {
            "id": 178581 # 250 GB storage space
        }
    ],
    "osFormatType": {
        "id": 12,
        "keyName": "LINUX",
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type"
    }
}
```

is my order. I have tried it with and without the complex type.

> SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError:
>   SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidData): Invalid data
>   on the order for property: osFormatType. No OS format type key name
>   set. Please provide a valid value

is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the API does not know what container your order is using, normally you do not need to specify it but in this case you need it.

Try this:

```
enduranceOrder = {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise", 
    "location": 1441195,
    "packageId": 240,
    "quantity": 48,
    "prices": [
        {
            "id": 45064 # endurance
        },
        {
            "id": 45104 # block storage
        },
        {
            "id": 178501 # 10 IOPS
        },
        {
            "id": 178581 # 250 GB storage space
        }
    ],
    "osFormatType": {
        "id": 12,
        "keyName": "LINUX",
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type"
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot Nelson. Regarding these Complex types, is this just specifying where these priceId's (items) are located?

Also for adding tags to the order, I'm assuming this can't be done at the time of ordering?

Comment: Sorry i do not undertand your question,but in order to know what complextype to use you need to look at documentation http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise

Comment: Thanks for your help nelson

Comment: mm if I do not wrong tags cannot be added to the storage devices I think there are question about that in stackoverflow, but you cannot set tags at order time that needs to be done after ordening